# Let $f:R\to[3,5]$ be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=3$,then find $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:R\to[3,5]$ be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=3$,then find $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x).$

---

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ means the horizontal asymptote of $f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ means the horizontal asymptote of $f'(x)$.It is given that their sum is $3$ but i do not know how to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^x (f(x)+f'(x))}{e^x} = \lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$$

Comment: I do not understand how you got $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^x (f(x)+f'(x))}{e^x} $ from $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^x f(x)}{e^x} $?@JimmyR

Comment: By L'Hopital's rule.